# How to resize TabContols by holding the emptyspace in the tab strip

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have  two tab controls stacked (using dockpanel) in a way that the empty space overlaps of their Tabstrips overlaps. I have to let users to resize these two tabcontrols height, especially the bottom one if they need.. Is there any way i can hold the emptyspace next to TabHeaders and drag it to resize?

```
<DockPanel>
    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="200" Margin="0,-20,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="tab 1"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="tab2"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>

    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 3" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 4" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the XAML.  Most likely you want a grid with a GridSplitter.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx

Comment: The bottom tabcontrol doesn't always visible. Comes up as editor for data selected in the upper tabs.Couldn't figure out how to use Gridsplitter to be positioned below both tab controls in the middle. Thanks

Comment: Question and comment not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
    <osc:DockPanelSplitter DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0,-20,0,0" Height="20" Panel.ZIndex="-1"/>

    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 3" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 4" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Key is Panel.Zindex on [DockPanelSplitter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34377/DockPanel-Splitter-Control-for-WPF)